# Use my own SQLiteDatabase in an android application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to make an SQLiteDatabase on my computer and then I want to use this database in my application. I made the database but I can't make it work in the application.

Comment: What's the error? Post the Stack trace from the LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-2/

Comment: I had quite a hassle while trying to use my own SQLite database in one of my earlier projects. Back then, the problem I had was with file sizes. Android doesn't accept a DB size of more than 3mb, iirc. The trick back then was to change the extension to .mp3 and it worked magically.

Comment: Oh, yes.  I remember reading/hearing about that trick.  Glad you were able to get it working.